# Using a dynamically loaded function as a target with multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyside

I am working on a GUI that needs to do some heavy computation in the background and then update the GUI when the calculation is complete. The multiprocessing module seems to be a good solution since I can use the *apply_async* method to specify the target and callback function. The callback function is used to update the GUI with the result. However I am having difficulty when trying to combine multiprocessing with a dynamically loaded module as in the following code. The error message is ImportError: No module named calc.

Is the error due to the fact that multiprocessing just doesn't work with dynamically loaded modules? If not, are there any ideas on a better approach?

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import multiprocessing
import time
import sys
import os
import logging
import imp

PluginFolder = "plugins"
plugins = {}

def f(x):
    y = x*x
    time.sleep(2) #Simulate processing time.
    return y


def load_plugin(name):
    '''Load the python module 'name'
    '''
    location = os.path.join('.', PluginFolder)
    info = imp.find_module(name, [location])
    plugin = {"name": name, "info": info}
    plugins[name] = imp.load_module(name, *plugin["info"])


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.pool = multiprocessing.Pool() 
        load_plugin('calc') #load ./plugins/calc.py

        button1 = QPushButton('Calculate', self)
        button1.clicked.connect(self.calculate)
        button2 = QPushButton('Test', self)
        button2.clicked.connect(self.run_test)
        self.text = QTextEdit()

        vbox1 = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox1.addWidget(button1)
        vbox1.addWidget(button2)
        vbox1.addWidget(self.text)
        myframe = QFrame()
        myframe.setLayout(vbox1)

        self.setCentralWidget(myframe)
        self.show()
        self.raise_()



    def calculate(self):
        #self.pool.apply_async(f, [10], callback=self.update_gui) #This works

        #result = plugins['calc'].f(10) #this works
        #self.update_gui(result)

        self.pool.apply_async(plugins['calc'].f, [10], callback=self.update_gui) #This doesn't


    def update_gui(self, result):
        self.text.append('Calculation complete. Result = %d\n' % result)


    def run_test(self):
        self.text.append('Testing\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

In ./plugins/calc.py, the function f is defined as in the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work since you're loading your `calc` module as a top-level module. Since no module `calc` is present in your `sys.path` or in current directory, it can't be found by import statement. Replacing import statement with following will do the trick:

```
plugins[name] = imp.load_module('{}.{}'.format(PluginFolder, name), 
                     *plugin["info"])
```

For a `plugin.calc` being importable, `plugins` has to be a python module, i.e. contain a  `__init__.py` file.

Any `import <module>` statement in your plugins files, such as in `plugins/calc.py`, will lead to a warning,

```
RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'plugins' not found while handling absolute import import <module>
```

The reason is that import process looks if parent module contains `<module>`, and while inside `calc.py`, can't find parent `plugins` module. You can rid of the error explicetely specifying `plugins` module location with, for example `import plugins` statement in main code.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. There is a warning: _.\plugins\calc.py:6: RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'plugins' not found while handling absolute import_
and an error: _PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed_

Comment: @mr_js please clarify your code structure, do you have `__init__.py` in you `plugins` folder; where is your main code located?

Comment: Thanks. The solution was to add `__init__.py` to the plugins folder and now your answer of changing the name to `plugins.calc` works. However the warning persists: _.\plugins\calc.py:6: RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'plugins' not found while handling absolute import
  import time_

Comment: @alco Thanks for your explanation. Works now.